# How do I install Vancouver style for Word 2016?

Tags: windows-10, styles, microsoft-word-2016, citations, bibliography

How do I install Vancouver style for Word 2016? I've found [a YouTube video instructing the user to search online for a 'Vancouver.xsl' file](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8PE4FH1lXZc), but this vague instruction seems a way to introduce viruses into your computer.

Comment: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-mso_2016/how-do-i-download-the-vancouver-referencing-style/09ea1cbd-d682-451d-8538-c2b9360ee7c5

Answer (score 4):

You need to download the reference styles from BibWord

https://github.com/mback2k/bibword-styles
Click on the green button (right hand corner - download)

Download the styles.zip

Unzip the files from the styles.zip, you will see multiple files in the folder (these are the reference styles).

Install the reference styles. Need to close Microsoft Word completely before continuing.

Go to the Microsoft Word folder

This PC → Disk C: → Program Files → Microsoft Office → Office 12 → Bibliography → StyleCopy the reference styles from the unzipped zip file to Style folder

Tips: you can find many useful ideas from http://bibword.codeplex.com/  In the Discussions section.

Comment: How do I download styles.zip? I do not see it on that webpage. I clicked 'download archive' but this zip appears to be the files of that website, without styles.zip.

Comment: Note: Newer versions of MS Office may have slightly different folder locations, such as:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\Bibliography\Style
(Notice the 'root' folder)

Comment: If you are using Office365, you need to add the .XSL file to C:\Users\<your username>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Bibliography\Style

Answer (score 1):

This what worked with me on Windows, not Mac (but maybe it could help)

after you download the styles from the previously mentioned bibword website ( that was the only one I found having those styles to date), then copy the folder.(you have to extract EVERY file, usually its under sourcecode- bibword, or search them all until you find style, its there somewhere lol). Now the other method that worked with me by coincidence is as follows:
open: 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\Bibliography

then paste the whole "style" folder.

then re-open Word, and it will be there
hope this one works!:)

Answer (score 1):

Another [Github repo](https://github.com/codingo/BibWord%E2%89%A4), which is actively maintained, contains the Vancouver style, which is fixed in [a recent pull request](https://github.com/codingo/BibWord/pull/14).

It also contains instructions on how to install the style files for the newest version of Word, on both Windows and Mac.